# Extract overlapping matches using split

Tags: java, regex, split

How can I extract overlapping matches from an input using `String.split()`?

For example, if trying to find matches to `"aba"`:

```
String input = "abababa";
String[] parts = input.split(???);
```

Expected output:

```
[aba, aba, aba]
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not `[ ababa, ababa ]` or can you only overlap one character? In any case I suspect you can't do this with a regex. Out of interest, why do you want to do this? How would you split `cababa`?

Comment: Are you sure `split` is what you want? It sounds more like you're trying `find` matches.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Edited question to make it more clear. Sorry for not adding the sought after match to the question.

Answer (score 5):

`String#split` will not give you overlapping matches. Because a particular part of the string, will only be included in a unique index, of the array obtained, and not in two indices.

You should use `Pattern` and `Matcher` classes here. 
You can use this regex: -

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?=(aba))");
```

And use `Matcher#find` method to get all the overlapping matches, and print `group(1)` for it.

The above regex matches every empty string, that is followed by `aba`, then just print the 1st captured group. Now since `look-ahead` is *zero-width* assertion, so it will not consume the string that is matched. And hence you will get all the overlapping matches.

```
String input = "abababa";
String patternToFind = "aba";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?=" + patternToFind + ")");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(patternToFind + " found at index: " + matcher.start());
}
```

**Output: -**

```
aba found at index: 0
aba found at index: 2
aba found at index: 4
```

Comment: Why have you created a group? As usual, you have use too more code/complication than needed. Here's a challenge for you: If you eliminate the group and simplify the code, I'll accept this answer.

Comment: @Bohemian. You can just remove that group, and print `aba` instead of `group 1`. That group is nothing but the pattern that you are matching. And that you know.

Comment: @Bohemian.. There you go. Edited to remove group.

Comment: Know we're talking! The most elegant code is usually the simplest/least amount of code. By removing the group you a) simplified the regex and b) made use of a more straightforward part of the Matcher API

Comment: @Bohemian.. Well, you are right that grouping was not required here, as you know what pattern you are looking for. But, it won't make much difference as far as this case is concerned. But, at the end, it's all on you. What you like, and what you are comfortable with. :)

Comment: @Bohemian: I think without grouping is worse. It doesn't matter in this case since you match a fixed width pattern, but if the pattern is variable-width, then the capturing group will allow you to get the text matched by the pattern.

Comment: @nhahtdh I (of course) disagree. It is trivial, and I think preferable due to clarity, to have the *whole* pattern match the target (where possible). By using a group, when you read the code you come across the regex first, then later you read that it extracts a *group*, so you go back to the regex to re-read it with that knowledge. Without groups you need only one reading pass.

Comment: @Bohemian: I'm not sure what you are talking about. If you are talking about the flow of the Java code then the discussion is irrelevant.

Comment: @nhahtdh I talking about a human reading the code (there's no other type of reader, actually). Code readability is paramount.

Comment: @Bohemian.. I have to say that, but your reasoning behind not using `capture group` is not that strong. Without Capture groups, half of the power of Regex is lost. It is not needed in this example, doesn't justify that it is not at all required. For e.g., suppose I say you to find out all the numbers followed by a `#`, and also the character after that `#` in this string - `"asf234#afl234#sdf"`, how are you going to achieve this? Capture group are necessary when you want to extract some part of the target string, based on some pattern.

Comment: Like in the above case you would just use the pattern - `(\d)#(.)`, and extract the two capture groups. And as far as human-readability is concerned, I don't think that is affected at all. Reading Captured group is not something, that has to be stressed upon so much. It is that common in Regex.

Answer (score 3):

I would use indexOf.

```
for(int i = text.indexOf(find); i >= 0; i = text.indexOf(find, i + 1))
   System.out.println(find + " found at " + i);
```

Comment: I really like the brevity, but I was going for a regex-based solution. Could this be modified to use a regex to find the pattern?

Comment: You could use Rohit Jain's solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a correct use of `split()`. From the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29):

> Splits this string around matches of the given regular expression.

Seems to me that you are not trying to split the string but to find all matches of your regular expression in the string. For this you would have to use a [Matcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html), and some extra code that loops on the `Matcher` to find all matches and then creates the array.

Comment: It would need some trick with the regex for it to work with Matcher (zero width look-around).